# What does the background color of Things indicate?

Tags: paper-mario-sticker-star

On the lower screen, the Things album shows you all of the Things in your inventory, and the background color for the Things is different.  For example, the Pillow is orange, the Goat is pink, and the Boom Box is blue.  What do these different colors indicate?

Comment: I've noticed that they indicate the size of the Thing. Red is large, blue is medium, and orange is small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Krazer has the right of it - the color indicates the size of Sticker that the Thing will create when the Thing is Flung.

- Orange: Small, 1 sticker square
- Blue: Medium, 1.5 sticker square
- Pink: Large, 2 sticker squares